# All windows reset their positions to the primary monitor after sleep

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I got a new secondary monitor a couple days ago, Acer B326HK. I had a multi-monitor setup before on the same W10 laptop and didn't experience any issues.

When the laptop and the monitor go to sleep, all the open windows move to the monitor that is selected as primary. I tried looking into the monitor settings but didn't find anything suspicious. What could be causing such behaviour? Is there any fix that would prevent it or any solution that would automatically put the windows back to them monitors they belong to?

System details:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 22H2
- GPU: Intel Iris Xe (i5 1145G7)
- Monitor: Acer B326HK, connected via HDMI